# Lookup Values by Corresponding Column Header in Pandas 1.2.0 or newer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The operation [`pandas.DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) is "Deprecated since version 1.2.0", and has since invalidated a lot of previous answers.

This post attempts to function as a canonical resource for looking up corresponding row col pairs in pandas versions 1.2.0 and newer.

## Standard LookUp Values With Default Range Index

Given the following DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
  Col  A  B
0   B  1  5
1   A  2  6
2   A  3  7
3   B  4  8
```

I would like to be able to lookup the corresponding value in the column specified in `Col`:

I would like my result to look like:

```py
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   B  4  8    8
```

---

## Standard LookUp Values With a Non-Default Index

### Non-Contiguous Range Index

Given the following DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]}, 
                  index=[0, 2, 8, 9])

  Col  A  B
0   B  1  5
2   A  2  6
8   A  3  7
9   B  4  8
```

I would like to preserve the index but still find the correct corresponding Value:

```py
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
2   A  2  6    2
8   A  3  7    3
9   B  4  8    8
```

### MultiIndex

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]))

    Col  A  B
C E   B  1  5
  F   A  2  6
D E   A  3  7
  F   B  4  8
```

I would like to preserve the index but still find the correct corresponding Value:

```py
    Col  A  B  Val
C E   B  1  5    5
  F   A  2  6    2
D E   A  3  7    3
  F   B  4  8    8
```

---

## LookUp with Default For Unmatched/Not-Found Values

Given the following DataFrame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

  Col  A  B
0   B  1  5
1   A  2  6
2   A  3  7
3   C  4  8  # Column C does not correspond with any column
```

I would like to look up the corresponding values if one exists otherwise I'd like to have it default to `0`

```py
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   C  4  8    0  # Default value 0 since C does not correspond
```

---

## LookUp with Missing Values in the lookup Col

Given the following DataFrame:

```py
   Col  A  B
0    B  1  5
1    A  2  6
2    A  3  7
3  NaN  4  8  # <- Missing Lookup Key
```

I would like any `NaN` values in `Col` to result in a `NaN` value in `Val`

```py
   Col  A  B  Val
0    B  1  5  5.0
1    A  2  6  2.0
2    A  3  7  3.0
3  NaN  4  8  NaN  # NaN to indicate missing
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Standard LookUp Values With Any Index

The documentation on [Looking up values by index/column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) recommends using NumPy indexing via [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) as the replacement for the deprecated [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
                  index=[0, 2, 8, 9])

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

`df`

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   B  4  8    8
```

[`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) is used to convert the column encode the values as an "enumerated type".

```py
idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
# idx = array([0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
# col = Index(['B', 'A'], dtype='object')
```

Notice that `B` corresponds to `0` and `A` corresponds to `1`. [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is used to ensure that columns appear in the same order as the enumeration:

```py
df.reindex(columns=col)

   B  A  # B appears First (location 0) A appers second (location 1)
0  5  1
1  6  2
2  7  3
3  8  4
```

We need to create an appropriate range indexer compatible with NumPy indexing.

The standard approach is to use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) based on the length of the DataFrame:

```
np.arange(len(df))

[0 1 2 3]
```

Now NumPy indexing will work to select values from the DataFrame:

```py
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

[5 2 3 8]
```

***Note**: This approach will always work regardless of type of index.

### MultiIndex

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]))

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

```
    Col  A  B  Val
C E   B  1  5    5
  F   A  2  6    2
D E   A  3  7    3
  F   B  4  8    8
```

## Why use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and not [`df.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) directly?

### Standard Contiguous Range Index

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[df.index, idx]
```

In this case only, there is no error as the result from [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) is the same as the [`df.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html).
`df`

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   B  4  8    8
```

### Non-Contiguous Range Index Error

Raises IndexError:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
                  index=[0, 2, 8, 9])

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[df.index, idx]
```

```
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[df.index, idx]

IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

### MultiIndex Error

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]))

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[df.index, idx]
```

Raises IndexError:

```
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[df.index, idx]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

---

## LookUp with Default For Unmatched/Not-Found Values

There are a few approaches.

First let's look at what happens by default if there is a non-corresponding value:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
#   Col  A  B
# 0   B  1  5
# 1   A  2  6
# 2   A  3  7
# 3   C  4  8

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5  5.0
1   A  2  6  2.0
2   A  3  7  3.0
3   C  4  8  NaN  # NaN Represents the Missing Value in C
```

If we look at *why* the `NaN` values are introduced, we will find that when [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) goes through the column it will enumerate all groups present regardless of whether they correspond to a column or not.

For this reason, when we [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the DataFrame we will end up with the following result:

```py
idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df.reindex(columns=col)
```

```py
idx = array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
col = Index(['B', 'A', 'C'], dtype='object')
df.reindex(columns=col)
   B  A   C
0  5  1 NaN
1  6  2 NaN
2  7  3 NaN
3  8  4 NaN  # Reindex adds the missing column with the Default `NaN`
```

If we want to specify a default value, we can specify the `fill_value` argument of [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) which allows us to modify the behaviour as it relates to missing column values:

```py
idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df.reindex(columns=col, fill_value=0)
```

```py
idx = array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
col = Index(['B', 'A', 'C'], dtype='object')
df.reindex(columns=col, fill_value=0)
   B  A  C
0  5  1  0
1  6  2  0
2  7  3  0
3  8  4  0  # Notice reindex adds missing column with specified value `0`
```

This means that we can do:

```py
idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
df['Val'] = df.reindex(
    columns=col, 
    fill_value=0  # Default value for Missing column values
).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

`df`:

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   C  4  8    0
```

*Notice the `dtype` of the column is `int`, since `NaN` was never introduced, and, therefore, the column type was not changed.

---

## LookUp with Missing Values in the lookup Col

[`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) has a default `na_sentinel=-1`, meaning that when `NaN` values appear in the column being factorized the resulting `idx` value is `-1`

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', np.nan],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
#    Col  A  B
# 0    B  1  5
# 1    A  2  6
# 2    A  3  7
# 3  NaN  4  8  # <- Missing Lookup Key

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'])
# idx = array([ 0,  1,  1, -1], dtype=int64)
# col = Index(['B', 'A'], dtype='object')
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
#    Col  A  B  Val
# 0    B  1  5    5
# 1    A  2  6    2
# 2    A  3  7    3
# 3  NaN  4  8    4 <- Value From A
```

This `-1` means that, by default, we'll be pulling from the last column when we reindex. Notice the `col` still only contains the values `B` and `A`. Meaning, that we will end up with the value from `A` in `Val` for the last row.

The easiest way to handle this is to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `Col` with some value that cannot be found in the column headers.

Here I use the empty string `''`:

```py
idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'].fillna(''))
# idx = array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
# col = Index(['B', 'A', ''], dtype='object')
```

Now when I reindex, the `''` column will contain `NaN` values meaning that the lookup produces the desired result:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', np.nan],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

idx, col = pd.factorize(df['Col'].fillna(''))
df['Val'] = df.reindex(columns=col).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

`df`:

```
   Col  A  B  Val
0    B  1  5  5.0
1    A  2  6  2.0
2    A  3  7  3.0
3  NaN  4  8  NaN  # Missing as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

## Other Approaches to LookUp

There are 2 other approaches to performing this operation:

### apply (Intuitive, but quite slow)

[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) can be used on `axis=1` in order to use the Column values as the key:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[row['Col']], axis=1)
```

`df`

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   B  4  8    8
```

This operation will work regardless of index type:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
                  index=[0, 2, 8, 9])

#   Col  A  B
# 0   B  1  5
# 2   A  2  6
# 8   A  3  7
# 9   B  4  8

df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[row['Col']], axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
2   A  2  6    2
8   A  3  7    3
9   B  4  8    8
```

When dealing with Missing/Non-Corresponding Values we can use [`Series.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) can be used to remedy this issue:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'C', np.nan],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

#    Col  A  B
# 0    B  1  5
# 1    A  2  6
# 2    C  3  7 <- Non Corresponding
# 3  NaN  4  8 <- Missing

df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Col']), axis=1)
```

```
   Col  A  B  Val
0    B  1  5  5.0
1    A  2  6  2.0
2    C  3  7  NaN  # Missing value
3  NaN  4  8  NaN  # Missing value
```

With Default Value

```py
df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Col'], default=-1), axis=1)
```

```
   Col  A  B  Val
0    B  1  5    5
1    A  2  6    2
2    C  3  7   -1  # Default -1
3  NaN  4  8   -1  # Default -1
```

`apply` is extremely flexible and modifications are straightforward, however, the general iterative approach, as well as all the individual `Series` lookups can become extremely costly in large DataFrames.

---

### get_indexer (limited)

[`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) can be used to convert the column to index values into an indexer for the DataFrame. This means there is no reason to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the DataFrame as the indexer corresponds to the DataFrame as a whole.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df['Val'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df['Col'])]
```

`df`

```
  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5    5
1   A  2  6    2
2   A  3  7    3
3   B  4  8    8
```

This approach is reasonably fast, however, missing values are represented by `-1` meaning that if a value is missing it will grab the value from the `-1` column (The last column in the DataFrame).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'C']})

#    A  B Col <- Col is now the Last Col
# 0  1  5   B
# 1  2  6   A
# 2  3  7   A
# 3  4  8   C <- Notice Col `C` does not correspond to a Valid Column Header
df['Val'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df['Col'])]
```

`df`:

```py
   A  B Col Val
0  1  5   B   5
1  2  6   A   2
2  3  7   A   3
3  4  8   C   C  # <- Value from the last column in the DataFrame (index -1)
```

It is also notable that *not* reindexing the DataFrame means converting the *entire* DataFrame to numpy. This can be *very* costly if there are many unrelated columns that all need converted:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: 10,
                   2: 20,
                   3: 't',
                   4: 40,
                   5: np.nan,
                   'Col': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df['Val'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df['Col'])]
```

```py
df.to_numpy()

[[10 20 't' 40 nan 'B' 1 5 5]
 [10 20 't' 40 nan 'A' 2 6 2]
 [10 20 't' 40 nan 'A' 3 7 3]
 [10 20 't' 40 nan 'B' 4 8 8]]
```

Compared to the reindexing approach which only contains columns relevant to the column values:

```py
df.reindex(columns=['B', 'A']).to_numpy()
[[5 1]
 [6 2]
 [7 3]
 [8 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to build a tuple of the lookup columns, pivot the dataframe, and select the relevant columns with the tuples:

```py
cols = [(ent, ent) for ent in df.Col.unique()]

df.assign(Val = df.pivot(index = None, columns = 'Col')
                  .reindex(columns = cols)
                  .ffill(axis=1)
                  .iloc[:, -1])

  Col  A  B  Val
0   B  1  5  5.0
2   A  2  6  2.0
8   A  3  7  3.0
9   B  4  8  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible method is to use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
df['value'] = (df.melt('Col', ignore_index=False)
                 .loc[lambda x: x['Col'] == x['variable'], 'value'])
print(df)

# Output:
  Col  A  B  value
0   B  1  5      5
1   A  2  6      2
2   A  3  7      3
3   B  4  8      8
```

This method also works *with Missing/Non-Corresponding Values*:

```
df['value'] = (df.melt('Col', ignore_index=False)
                 .loc[lambda x: x['Col'] == x['variable'], 'value'])
print(df)

# Output
   Col  A  B  value
0    B  1  5    5.0
1    A  2  6    2.0
2    C  3  7    NaN
3  NaN  4  8    NaN
```

You can replace `.loc[...]` by `query(...)` but it's little slower although more expressive:

```
df['value'] = df.melt('Col', ignore_index=False).query('Col == variable')['value']
```