# Select value from column by row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following Data frame (the actual is huge with 100 columns and 500K rows)

[image]

I want to create a new column called `NewCol` which will contain for each row, the value from the correct column (chosen by `Col`)
Meaning :

[image]

Is there an elegant way to do this, without just iterating over the rows with a simple for loop ?

Comment: I updated the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352472/lookup-values-by-corresponding-column-header-in-pandas-1-2-0-or-newer) with a simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515784/15239951) IMHO